# Unable to connect to MySQL database through Visual studio 2012

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

We encountered an error while trying to connect. Here is my code :

```
public void BindData()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=abc");
    con.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from register", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

But it gives following error :

[image: screenshot error page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the reference Renci.SshNet is existing in your Projects's references. If none, find the .dll file then add it respectively.

Regards,

Hack Dawg